Is it possible to simplify this excel formula?
I'm using this formula currently but it feels a little long. Is it possible to simplify this?
=IFS(AND(CU28>=45,CU28<50),MROUND(CU28, 10), CU28<45, CU28, CU28>100, MROUND(CU28, 100), CU28>=50, CU28)

I've tried putting together CU28<45, CU28 with CU28>=50, CU28 to turn it into AND(CU28<45, CU28>=50), CU28 then put it inside the IFS formula along with the rest but it doesn't work. Is it possible to put them together since in the end, I just want the cell to show the original value in CU28 if it fulfils those two conditions?

[codereview.se]?

This seems to do it:
=IF(CU28>100,MROUND(CU28,100),IF(AND(CU28>=45,CU28<=50),50,CU28))


A little bit shorter if values are whole numbers:
=MROUND(CU28,IF(AND(CU28>=45,CU28<50),10,IF(CU28>100,100,1)))

Otherwise you can set multiple to something 0.00000001 or even lower instead of 1

=IFS(AND(CU28>=45,CU28<50),MROUND(CU28, 10),
     CU28<45,              CU28,
     CU28>100,             MROUND(CU28, 100),
     CU28>=50,             CU28)

This can be written in pseudo-code as:
IF (CU28>=45 AND CU28<50)
THEN MROUND(CU28, 10)
ELSE IF CU28<45
     THEN CU28
     ELSE IF CU28>100
          THEN MROUND(CU28, 100)
          ELSE IF CU28>=50
               THEN CU28

There are three possible results:

MROUND(CU28, 10), if (CU28>=45 AND CU28<50)
MROUND(CU28, 100), if (CU28>100)
CU28, if (CU28 < 45) OR (CU28 >= 50 AND CU28 <= 100)

The condition of number 3. can be expressed in Excel-style as: OR((CU28 < 45),AND(CU28 >= 50, CU28 <= 100)).
From here, you know what to do :-)
Edit:
I just realise that 3. is in fact just the ELSE-case of the rest, so this makes it all very simple :-)

MROUND(CU28, 10) is pointless as all the numbers from 45 to 50 just go to 50. So it can be a constant.
